# Insert in list values from database

Tags: c#, list, select

I have a function that selects from database some column values. I would like those selected values to be inserted in a list with maximum 26 items. How can I do that? One "row" from list contains the `question` with `answer1,answer2,answer2,option1,option2,option3`. How can I do that? I don't really know how to work with lists.

```
private void select()
{
    if (index.connect.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
        index.connect.Close(); 
    }

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(dataA, index.connect);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    using (index.connect)
    {
        index.connect.Open();
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                label2.Text = rdr["question"].ToString();
                label3.Text = rdr["answer1"].ToString();
                label4.Text = rdr["answer2"].ToString();
                label5.Text = rdr["answer3"].ToString();
                r1 = (int)rdr["option1"];
                r2 = (int)rdr["option2"];
                r3 = (int)rdr["option3"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            index.connect.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like limit to be only 26 items in your query to database? If this what you mean, you may use Array. You can limit arrays to be size that you want.

Comment: No andrey, I want to limit the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to implenet what you ask for.

In the **SQL level**, there's a simple solution - you can select a certain amount of items, I.E 26, by using the keyword "Top".

for example,

```
SELECT TOP 26 Grade FROM StudentsTable;
```

In the **Application level**, you can programmatically select the 26 items you want; For example, if you're getting them from an ASP application in textboxes and the database interaction is activated from a button_Click event, you can Select them in the function itself ; To illustrate, let's say you want to select the maximum 26 values out of 50 labels named Label, you'll have in the button.Click:

```
List<int> MyLabels = FindMaxValues(<Your array of labels>, 26)
//Database stuff with MyLabels
```

And the function itself:

```
private static List<int> FindMaxValues(Labels[] myLbls, int AmountOutOfMax)
{
int LabelValue=0
for(int i=0;i<AmountOutOfMax;i++)
 {
  for(int k=0;k<50;k++)
  {
  LabelValue=int.Parse(myLbls[k])
   // find max, etc.
   }
 }
}
```

My point is - There are many solutions, this question is somewhat vague - You should find what is right for you depending on your application, and go for it;

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, I will modify this function for my script, I get it.